# Как организовать delay в React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть сайдбар, перед тем как он открывается происходит рендеринг его чайлдов, что немного замедляет открытие. Я решил оттянуть рендеринг и после открытие 1-2 секунды показывать спиннер, а потом вместо него подставлять содержимое. То есть задать в стейте сайдбара какой-то флаг, который после открытия сайдабара 2-3 секунды будет true  и соответственно я в рендере пропишу тернарным оператором условие при котором в этом случае буду отображать спиннер, по прошествии этого времени я буду делать setState  и менять флаг, соответственно пойдет перерисовка на содержимое меню. попробовал прямо в рендере перед return:

```
if (visibleTagBar) {
            setTimeout(()=> this.setState({showDefaultLoader: false}), 3000);
        }
```

Но это неправильно. Пробовал в componentWillmount/DidMount-срабатывает слишком рано. Как можно реализовать данную штуку?

Answer (score 1):

Идея с изменяемым параметром в state - очень правильная с точки зрения React-практик. Но есть ощущение, что вы могли где-то что-то не учесть.

> после открытие 1-2 секунды показывать спиннер, а потом вместо него подставлять содержимое

Содержимое не будет рендерится (если под содержимым вы подразумеваете child'ы), пока оно не появится в React-дереве. Если вы прячете child'ы до изменения `showDefaultLoader` в `true`, то они не будут рендерится до тех пор, пока `showDefaultLoader` не будет равен `true`. В этом случае самое топорное решение - скрывать child'ы не прямым удалением из дерева, а путём выставления на них стиля `opacity: 0` или даже `visibility: hidden` (если в их рендеринге не участвует DOM-дерево). Чтобы их скрыть таким образом - вы можете на их общий родитель навешивать отдельный класс при `showDefaultLoader: false`, который в стилях будет скрывать все дочерние child'ы.

> попробовал прямо в рендере перед return
>
> setTimeout(()=> this.setState({showDefaultLoader: false}), 3000);

Так не стоит делать. У вас render может вызываться множество раз при любом изменении state/props, и при этом будет запускаться этот таймер. Т.е. если за первые 2 секунды жизни компонента рендер отработал 20 раз, то вы запустите 20 копий этого таймера, каждая из которых выполнится, а при выполнении - последует перерендер, что опять же запустит снова этот таймер. В результате, браузер через некоторое время может зависнуть из-за постоянного увеличения числа таймеров. К тому же, при отключении компонента (когда вы перейдёте на другую страницу, где его нет) все ранее запущенные таймеры продолжат работать, и попытаются обновить state компонента, которого уже нет, что приведёт к массовым ошибкам в консоли.